# How to find where a column ranks across a row using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Iowa = c(11, 12, 15),
  Wisconsin = c(10, 14, 12),
  Florida = c(14, 9, 11)
)
```

I want to get the rowwise rank for Iowa relative to the other columns. So the output would look like this:

```
out <- data.frame(
  Iowa = c(11, 12, 15),
  Wisconsin = c(10, 14, 12),
  Florida = c(14, 9, 11),
  IowaRank = c(2, 2, 1)
)
```

What's the best way to achieve this using R, ideally in a `dplyr` pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest will be `apply` to loop over the rows, apply the `rank` extract the first row

```
dat$IowaRank <- apply(-dat, 1, rank)[1,]
```

-output

```
dat
  Iowa Wisconsin Florida IowaRank
1   11        10      14        2
2   12        14       9        2
3   15        12      11        1
```

Or using `rowRanks` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
dat$IowaRank <- rowRanks(-as.matrix(dat))[,1]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(IowaRank = rank(-c_across(everything()))[1]) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   Iowa Wisconsin Florida IowaRank
  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1    11        10      14        2
2    12        14       9        2
3    15        12      11        1
```

Comment: I think that it is the first time Ive seen a non-`dplyr` solution that I would prefer over `dplyr`.

Comment: This is great, but what if the first column is actually a factor? Is there a way to skip over that?

Comment: @R.Baratheon If I assume that you are doing this on numeric columns `i1 <- sapply(dat, is.numeric); apply(-dat[i1], 1, rank)[1,]`. or with `dplyr`, it woud be `mutate(IowaRank = rank(-c_across(where(is.numeric)))[1])`

Comment: @R.Baratheon Or if you know the index, then just do `apply(dat[-1], 1, rank)[1,]`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ranks for all the columns using `dense_rank` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(-value)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = c(value, rank)) %>%
  select(-row)

#  value_Iowa value_Wisconsin value_Florida rank_Iowa rank_Wisconsin rank_Florida
#       <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>     <int>          <int>        <int>
#1         11              10            14         2              3            1
#2         12              14             9         2              1            3
#3         15              12            11         1              2            3
```

If you are interested only in rank of Iowa using `rowwise` you can do -

```
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(IowaRank = dense_rank(-c_across())[1])

#   Iowa Wisconsin Florida IowaRank
#  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>
#1    11        10      14        2
#2    12        14       9        2
#3    15        12      11        1
```